# Memoryleak and Async Targeting Pack for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, async-await

if apply Async Targeting Pack for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, want to know if developer still need to care about release event handler to avoid memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to know if developer still need to care about release event handler to avoid memory leak?

The Async Targeting Pack has no impact on events and event handlers.  It merely adds the extra functionality required to target .NET 4 with the new async/await syntax, which is completely unrelated to events and event handling.

Comment: thanks. Try to install it, but got description: This targeting pack is not required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Metro style apps. It is only required for projects targeting Silverlight 5 and .NET Framework 4.0. Earlier platform releases are not supported. So it means no need for SL5 +.NET 4.5???

Comment: @KentZhou Yes - .NET 4.5 already has all of the requires support.  The targeting pack is just so you can make .NET 4/SL 5 applications using the new async/await keywords.